# Setting a 1 second time limit does not stop the script after 1 second

Tags: php, time-limiting

I am calling shell commands that might take a while and should be interrupted after 5 minutes. Anyways, this does not seem to work.

I boiled it down to the following test code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(1);
echo 'TL = ' . set_time_limit(1) . PHP_EOL;
sleep(5);
echo 'finished, not interrupted';
```

This gives me the following output:

```
TL = 1 finished, not interrupted
```

So it looks the timelimit is set properly - but the script still runs for 5 seconds.

I am using PHP version 5.6.11 with mod_php

Comment: try `ini_set("max_execution_time", 1);`

Comment: @SamSwift웃 That wouldn't help.

Comment: @meagar, just a thought, an idea if you would :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP time limit is only enforced when the program is actually executing. `sleep` delays do not necessarily count as such, [as per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> Note: The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer, more a comment.

Comment: @SamSwift웃: It's an answer that says "the observed behavior is correct, only your expectation is wrong".

Comment: @SamSwift웃 It totally answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Time spent `sleep`ing does not count towards script execution time.

Comment: I don't believe this is an answer, more a comment.